# Multivariate limit using multivariate Taylor

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I'd like to compute the following limit using the multivariate Taylor theorem:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{x}
$$
I know that this limit is $0$, since
$$
\frac{e^{xy}-1}{x}=y\frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy}
$$

and $e^{f(x,y)}-1$ and $f(x,y)$ are equivalent infinitesimals. However, I want to understanding how to correctly use multivariate Taylor expansions to compute the limit. Given that the denominator in the last expression is $xy$, I computed the second order Taylor polynomial, which is $1+xy$. I know that one of the expressions of the remainder that is usually helpful when dealing with limits is $R_2(x,y) = w(x,y)\|\ (x,y)\|\ ^2=w(x,y)\cdot(x^2+y^2)$, with $w(x,y)\to 0$ as $(x,y)\to 0$. So we have
$$
\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y} = \frac{1+xy+ w(x,y)\cdot(x^2+y^2)-1}{y} = \frac{xy+ w(x,y)\cdot(x^2+y^2)}{y} = x + \frac{w(x,y)\cdot(x^2+y^2)}{y}
$$

Obviously $\lim{(x,y)\to (0,0)} x = 0$, but how do I know that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{w(x,y)\cdot(x^2+y^2)}{y} = 0$?

Comment: Here you can use the 1 variable taylor theorem to get $e^{z} = 1 + z + z^2w(z)$ with $w(z) = O(1)$ as $z \to 0$.

Comment: @Kakashi I'd like to understand how to compute the limit using multivariate Taylor. I am practicing the use of multivariate Taylor for limit computation.

Comment: I am not sure multivariate Taylor (in its standard form) of $e^{xy}$ will help here, because there will always be a remainder term that scales as $x^k$, for which you cannot say anything about how $x^k/y$ behaves as $(x,y) \to 0$.

Comment: @user210089 You can use 2 variable Taylor theorem, but you can't use the crude remainder as you did. Try using the exact integral formula for the remainder.

Comment: @Kakashi Would it be possible with Lagrange remainder instead? The notes I am practicing with do not include the integral form, and I'd prefer to stick ti what I 'should' use.

Comment: It think it is possible; it's something to try. I see that you need the second order terms to get $1 + xy$, so the remainder will involve 3rd partial derivatives of $e^{xy}$. It should be straightforward to form the remainder term and check whether it's easy to see that it goes to $0$. I just use the integral form by default because it works in cases where the Lagrange one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Kakashi The coefficient of $x^3$ is $e^{ab}b^3$, being $(a,b)$ some point between the origin and $(x,y)$. It is not $0$ in general. What should I do?

Comment: @user210089 You just have to show that the remainder term divided by $x$ goes to $0$ as $x, y \to 0$. We have $|e^{ab}b^3| \leq e^{ab}|x|^3$ and since $e^{xy} \to 1$ as $x, y \to 0$, this is $\leq (1 + 1/2)|x|^3$ when $|(x, y)|$ is small enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's recall that the bivariate Taylor series of a function $f(x,y)$ around $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m\ge0} \left.\frac{\partial^{n+m}f}{\partial x^n \partial y^m}\right|_{(x_0,y_0)} \frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}\frac{(y-y_0)^m}{m!},
$$
where you can always assimilate the tail of the series to a remainder if you wish. In the present case, we are interested in the expansion of $f(x,y) = \frac{e^{xy}-1}{x}$ around the origin. By chance, we are not obliged to compute all the partial derivatives, because $f(x,y) = y\,g(xy)$, where
$$
g(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z} = \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{z^k}{(k+1)!},
$$
as you already stated, so that
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{x^ky^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} = y + \frac{1}{2}xy + \frac{1}{6}x^2y^3 + \ldots
$$
In consequence, the only non-vanishing terms in $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y)$ will be the constant ones, but there is none of them, since the lowest degree in the expansion corresponds to $k = 0$ and is associated to the term $y$, hence $f(0,0) = 0$ in the end, as expected.